# Tensorboard Pytorch does not show runs

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

I am new to tensorboard with Pytorch.
I followed the codes at https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensorboard.html

And it generates a folder accordingly
[image]

In the command line, I run
[image]

But at http://localhost:6006/, it does not load accordingly. It keeps loading but show
[image]

I tried to use "tensorboard dev upload --logdir 'runs'" as well.
[image]

But it still shows nothing.
[image]

No event file is found here.

[image]

I am using tensorboard 2.7.0, torch 1.7, cuda 11.0.
[image]

Can anyone give me some help? Thanks a lot!!